# mvc Html.BeginForm different URL schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm creating a form for a DropDown like this:

```
@{
    Html.BeginForm("View", "Stations", FormMethod.Get);
}
@Html.DropDownList("id", new SelectList(ViewBag.Stations, "Id", "Name"), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
@{
    Html.EndForm();
}
```

If I choose a value from my dropdown I get redirected to the correct controller but the URL is not as I would like to have it:

> /Stations/View?id=f2cecc62-7c8c-498d-b6b6-60d48a862c1c

What I want is:

> /Stations/View/f2cecc62-7c8c-498d-b6b6-60d48a862c1c

So how do I get the id= querystring parameter replaced by the more simple URL Scheme I want?

Comment: You cant. Your browser knows nothing about you route configurations. A form with `FormMethod.Get` will always post back the values of its controls as query string values (unless you were to use javascript to intercept the submit and build your own url)

Comment: OK, thanks for this. If you post this as Answer, I'll accept that as solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

A form with `FormMethod.Get` will always post back the values of its form controls as query string values. A browser cannot generate a url based on your route configurations because they are server side code.

If you really wanted to generate `/Stations/View/f2cecc62-7c8c-498d-b6b6-60d48a862c1c`, then you could use javascript/jquery to build your own url and redirect

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("View", "Stations", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("id", new SelectList(ViewBag.Stations, "Id", "Name"))
}

var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("View", "Stations")';
$('#id').change(function() {
    location.href = baseUrl + '/' $(this).val();
});
```

Side note: Submitting on the `.change()` event is not expected behavior and is confusing to a user. Recommend you add a button to let the user make their selection, check it and then submit the form (handle the button's `.click()` event rather that the dropdownlist's `.change()` event)

Comment: If you ask me to add an answer so that you can accept it, at least have the  courtesy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "`id`"
from

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", new SelectList(ViewBag.Stations, "Id", "Name"), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Comment: and what name should I use instead of "id" ?

Comment: SO far I know name is not mandatory. As you have defined a name of form. This field's name will be assigned by default.

Comment: Html.DropDownList always requires a String value as name, every overload of the method requires it.